# Wrapper function vs bind performance NodeJs

Tags: javascript, node.js, performance, comparison, wrapper

I have a segment of code which is called in a for. The thing is I have to use either a bind or a wrapper function and performance is critical. So my question is: What is the fastest method of doing it and how much memory will each method use?

1. A anonymous wrapper function

   ```
   for (var i = 0; i < 999999; ++i) {
       foo(function(b, c) {
           fii(a, b, c);
       })
   };
   ```
2. A named wrapper function

   ```
   function fuu(b, c) {
       fii(a, b, c);
   };

   for (var i = 0; i < 999999; ++i) {
       foo(fuu);
   };
   ```
3. A bind

   ```
   for (var i = 0; i < 999999; ++i) {
       foo(fii.bind(fii, a));
   }
   ```

Comment: Similar JSPerf test case: http://jsperf.com/bind-vs-wrapper

Comment: What is stopping you from trying all three and testing performance yourself?

Comment: I want to know what are the differences, why it's faster that way and what are the memory usages. I don't just want to test it.